# How to make a reverse DNS lookup on CloudFlare in PHP?

Tags: php, dns, cloudflare, googlebot, gethostbyaddr

I have a website, but it is parsed as fake googlebot useragent. I want to filter out fake googlebot by doing reverse DNS lookup.
On a regular hosting, I could do this with

```
gethostbyaddr ($ _ SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

and was getting something like this crawl-66-249-79-164.googlebot.com
But on CLoudFlare I get the ip address of the CLoudFlare server, not googlebot.

Comment: you can try with `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`

Comment: Thanks. It exactly what I need